# Outlook Webaddin manifest doesn't load in Windows Outlook

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to add the permissions (<WebApplicationInfo>) for MS Graph in my manifest for an Outlook Webaddin but it doesn't work. The addin button doesn't come available in Windows Outlook.

This is my fully manifest:

```
...
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
...
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>xxx-xxxx-xxxx</Id>
      <Resource>https://graph.microsoft.com/xxx-xxxx-xxxx</Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>Mail.Send</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
      </Scopes>
    </WebApplicationInfo>
</VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

If I let the second section <VersionOverrides> away then it loads.

Does somebody know why?

```
npm run validate -- -p and validate-office-addin manifest.xml
```

says the manifest is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put everything under 
Like this:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>xxx-xxxx-xxxx</Id>
      <Resource>https://graph.microsoft.com/xxx-xxxx-xxxx</Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>Mail.Send</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
      </Scopes>
    </WebApplicationInfo>
</VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Crikkelieke sounds like you found a solution for your problem, can you please clarify what was the issue exactly? Both XML snippets in the question and in the answer look very similar.